# Why is strftime("%x") not working in my python code?

Tags: python, strftime

So I am trying to rename a file that has been downloaded to my downloads folder.

My code:

```
import os
from time import strftime

current_time = strftime("(%x-%Xp)")

old_name = r'C:/Users/name/Downloads/file.pdf'
new_name = r'C:/Users/name/Downloads/file'+current_time+'.pdf'
os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

However, I keep geting this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:/Users/darianmoore/Downloads/file.pdf' -> 'C:/Users/darianmoore/Downloads/file(12/31/19-10:47:47AM).pdf'
```

I'm very confused because if I use this code it works fine, but it's not the formatting I want:

```
import os
from time import strftime

current_time = strftime("(%m%d%y-%I%M%p)")

old_name = r'C:/Users/name/Downloads/file.pdf'
new_name = r'C:/Users/name/Downloads/file'+current_time+'.pdf'
os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

Comment: What format are you trying to get?

Comment: I don't think you can add colons or slashes to filenames in Windows.

Comment: Workaround: Simply format the time string so it doesn't contain any slashes and colons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File name cannot contain a slash. `file(12/31/19-10:47:47AM).pdf` does.